# solving computer performance by amdal's low speedup factor

Tags: performance

a program runs 100s. multiyply instructions are 80% of the program.There is need to make the program 2 times faster. how much should the multiply instruction be speedup achieve to reach the overall speedup level ?
pls help me to solve this question by amdal's low....

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

The running time is 80 s for multiplies and 20 s for the rest.

You need to bring this down to 30 / 20 s.